# Why Ubuntu auto swapon swap partition?

Tags: swap, fstab

I have a standard Ubuntu installation. After that, I disable swap entry in fstab. But, when power on the computer, Ubuntu automatically use that swap partition. Sometimes it does that, sometimes it does not. Why is that?

EDIT: I disable swap partition because I use zram and just keep swap partition for hibernation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching around for a while, I found this [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Swap). So that is `systemd` activates swap on boot.